# DateTime is Serializable but not serializing properly?

Tags: android, serialization, jodatime

I've noticed that in the newest version of Joda time (2.7), the `DateTime` class implements `Serializable`. Yay!

I tried to pass my object containing `DateTime` variable between activities putting it as `Serializable` extra. However after deserializing my object from `Intent` extra, my `DateTime` variable was `null`.

Am I still forced to use Parcelable with DateTime? How can it be gone after deserialization if it implements `Serializable`?

Comment: Can you show your code where you send and receive the intent?

Answer (score 0):

Just a stupid mistake of mine.

**Joda Time version 2.7 indeed supports serialization.**

I had my variable marked as `transient`... sorry